SDRAM interfacing like with parallel bus device using STM32F4 FMC
Followed by that post Emulating a defective LCD from a device and use another LCD
I'm trying to communicate with the device using FMC.
So my plane is to connect the whole D0 to D7 to FMC SDRAM Controller, plus CS1,CS2,A1.
I will react on IOWR falling edge and read the databus from FMC.
Now I tried to use stm32F4 CubeMX, and I have initialized the FMC, GPIOs,..etc.
I pulled D0 from FMC to high, and I'm issuing a read command from SD Controller, I read zero. My expectation is FMC should give me a read 1 on the bus of 16bit.
Here is a short cut of the code
// SDRAM mode register definitions
#define SDRAM_MODEREG_BURST_LENGTH_1             ((uint16_t)0x0000)
#define SDRAM_MODEREG_BURST_LENGTH_2             ((uint16_t)0x0001)
#define SDRAM_MODEREG_BURST_LENGTH_4             ((uint16_t)0x0002)
#define SDRAM_MODEREG_BURST_LENGTH_8             ((uint16_t)0x0003)
#define SDRAM_MODEREG_BURST_TYPE_SEQUENTIAL      ((uint16_t)0x0000)
#define SDRAM_MODEREG_BURST_TYPE_INTERLEAVED     ((uint16_t)0x0008)
#define SDRAM_MODEREG_CAS_LATENCY_2              ((uint16_t)0x0020)
#define SDRAM_MODEREG_CAS_LATENCY_3              ((uint16_t)0x0030)
#define SDRAM_MODEREG_OPERATING_MODE_STANDARD    ((uint16_t)0x0000)
#define SDRAM_MODEREG_WRITEBURST_MODE_PROGRAMMED ((uint16_t)0x0000)
#define SDRAM_MODEREG_WRITEBURST_MODE_SINGLE     ((uint16_t)0x0200)

// Refresh rate for SDRAM
#define REFRESH_COUNT                            ((uint32_t)0x0603)  // Adjust based on your SDRAM specs

// Main program
int main(void) {
    // HAL initialization
    HAL_Init();
    
    // Configure the system clock
    SystemClock_Config();
    
    // Initialize GPIO and FMC
    GPIO_Init();
    SDRAM_Init();

    // Variables for data
    uint16_t read_data = 0;

    // Read data from the SDRAM memory location 0xD0000000 (FMC SDRAM bank 1)
    uint16_t* sdram_address = (uint16_t*)0xD0000000;
    read_data = *sdram_address;

    // Infinite loop
    while (1) {
        // Add your application code here
    }
}


void GPIO_Init(void) {
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOG_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();

    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

    // Configure FMC data lines (PD0-PD15, PE0-PE15)
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_All;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF12_FMC;

    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    // Configure FMC address lines (PF0-PF5, PF12-PF15, PG0-PG5, PG9)
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1 | GPIO_PIN_2 | GPIO_PIN_3 |
                          GPIO_PIN_4 | GPIO_PIN_5 | GPIO_PIN_12 | GPIO_PIN_13 |
                          GPIO_PIN_14 | GPIO_PIN_15;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOF, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1 | GPIO_PIN_2 | GPIO_PIN_3 |
                          GPIO_PIN_4 | GPIO_PIN_5 | GPIO_PIN_9;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    // Configure FMC control lines (PC2 - SDNE0, PC3 - SDCKE0, PG10 - SDCLK, etc.)
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2 | GPIO_PIN_3;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5 | GPIO_PIN_6 | GPIO_PIN_7;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOH, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}

void SDRAM_Init(void) {
    __HAL_RCC_FMC_CLK_ENABLE();

    SDRAM_HandleTypeDef hsdram;
    FMC_SDRAM_TimingTypeDef SdramTiming;

    hsdram.Instance = FMC_SDRAM_DEVICE;
    hsdram.Init.SDBank = FMC_SDRAM_BANK1;
    hsdram.Init.ColumnBitsNumber = FMC_SDRAM_COLUMN_BITS_NUM_8;
    hsdram.Init.RowBitsNumber = FMC_SDRAM_ROW_BITS_NUM_12;
    hsdram.Init.MemoryDataWidth = FMC_SDRAM_MEM_BUS_WIDTH_16;
    hsdram.Init.InternalBankNumber = FMC_SDRAM_INTERN_BANKS_NUM_4;
    hsdram.Init.CASLatency = FMC_SDRAM_CAS_LATENCY_3;
    hsdram.Init.WriteProtection = FMC_SDRAM_WRITE_PROTECTION_DISABLE;
    hsdram.Init.SDClockPeriod = FMC_SDRAM_CLOCK_PERIOD_2;
    hsdram.Init.ReadBurst = FMC_SDRAM_RBURST_ENABLE;
    hsdram.Init.ReadPipeDelay = FMC_SDRAM_RPIPE_DELAY_1;

    // Timing configuration for read/write access
    SdramTiming.LoadToActiveDelay = 2;
    SdramTiming.ExitSelfRefreshDelay = 7;
    SdramTiming.SelfRefreshTime = 4;
    SdramTiming.RowCycleDelay = 7;
    SdramTiming.WriteRecoveryTime = 2;
    SdramTiming.RPDelay = 2;
    SdramTiming.RCDDelay = 2;

    if (HAL_SDRAM_Init(&hsdram, &SdramTiming) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    // Program the SDRAM external device
    FMC_SDRAM_CommandTypeDef Command;
    __IO uint32_t tmpmrd = 0;

    // Step 3: Configure a clock configuration enable command
    Command.CommandMode = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_CLK_ENABLE;
    Command.CommandTarget = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_TARGET_BANK1;
    Command.AutoRefreshNumber = 1;
    Command.ModeRegisterDefinition = 0;

    if (HAL_SDRAM_SendCommand(&hsdram, &Command, 0x1000) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    // Step 4: Insert 100 ms delay
    HAL_Delay(100);

    // Step 5: Configure a PALL (precharge all) command
    Command.CommandMode = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_PALL;
    Command.CommandTarget = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_TARGET_BANK1;
    Command.AutoRefreshNumber = 1;
    Command.ModeRegisterDefinition = 0;

    if (HAL_SDRAM_SendCommand(&hsdram, &Command, 0x1000) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    // Step 6: Configure an Auto Refresh command
    Command.CommandMode = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_AUTOREFRESH_MODE;
    Command.CommandTarget = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_TARGET_BANK1;
    Command.AutoRefreshNumber = 8;
    Command.ModeRegisterDefinition = 0;

    if (HAL_SDRAM_SendCommand(&hsdram, &Command, 0x1000) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    // Step 7: Program the external memory mode register
    tmpmrd = (uint32_t)SDRAM_MODEREG_BURST_LENGTH_1 |
                      SDRAM_MODEREG_BURST_TYPE_SEQUENTIAL |
                      SDRAM_MODEREG_CAS_LATENCY_3 |
                      SDRAM_MODEREG_OPERATING_MODE_STANDARD |
                      SDRAM_MODEREG_WRITEBURST_MODE_SINGLE;

    Command.CommandMode = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_LOAD_MODE;
    Command.CommandTarget = FMC_SDRAM_CMD_TARGET_BANK1;
    Command.AutoRefreshNumber = 1;
    Command.ModeRegisterDefinition = tmpmrd;

    if (HAL_SDRAM_SendCommand(&hsdram, &Command, 0x1000) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    // Step 8: Set the refresh rate counter
    // Set the device refresh rate
    HAL_SDRAM_ProgramRefreshRate(&hsdram, REFRESH_COUNT);
}


Why are you operating the FMC in SDRAM mode instead of a simpler SRAM mode?

@brhans Can you point the differences ? Also if you have time can you tell me the setup for SRAM if its appropriate
